# Order of a FIR Filter given the amount of coefficients

Tags: signal-processing

Does the order of a FIR filter correspond with the amount of coefficients? (E.g 36 filter coefficients = 36th order filter?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general yes, but note that many FIR filters are symmetric (gives linear phase, i.e. constant group delay) so in practice you may only have N / 2 distinct coefficients for an Nth order filter, with each coefficient being used for two corresponding filter stages.